# How can I emit smoke from just the outline of a model?

Tags: mesh, smoke-simulation

I know my way around Blender a bit, but I'm in no way an expert. What I am trying to do is have a humanoid mesh that is invisible, but have smoke emit from it's silhouette only, not it's volume. Is there a way to generate a mesh on just the outline of a model similar to backface culling with solidify modifier so that the smoke only generates at those locations?

I tried to keep the question short, but let me know if anything is unclear.
Thanks!

Comment: making a fire creature?

Answer (score 2):

Use the mesh as emitter. Use vertex painting to paint the “silhouette” as a vertex group. Set vertex group in smoke. Set volume to 0.

Answer (score 0):

While not a 'true' silhouette (as it's a slice through your model, rather than its true outline), one solution is to simply use a Boolean modifier on your model with a scaled cube (scaled right down in one dimension to make it a thin slice). This will produce a thin slice of your model that you can then emit the smoke from its faces :

[image: smoke emitted from slice]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add layer weight node in shader editor.
2. Connect the layer weight input to the factor of smoke shader